# Definition of contractible chain complex

Tags: homological-algebra

A relatively simple question. A book I'm reading states "a complex homotopic to the zero complex is called contractible"... but I don't understand the statement.

I know what it means for chain maps to be homotopic, but not chain complexes themselves. What does it mean for a complex to be homotopic to the zero complex?

Comment: 'homotopic' here means 'homotopy equivalent'.

Comment: that means the homologie of the complex is zero

Comment: Uh huh, and chain complexes are homotopy equivalent if they are isomorphic modulo chain homotopies, i.e. there exist chain maps F,G, so that FG, GF are homotopic to the appropriate identity maps.

Comment: The identity map of this chain complex is homotopic to the zero map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the statement isn't very precise. Indeed, it's *maps* that can be homotopic, while complexes can be *homotopy equivalent*. Two complexes $C$, $D$ are *homotopy equivalent* if there exists chain maps $f : C \to D$ and $g : D \to C$ such that $f \circ g$ is *homotopic* to $\operatorname{id}_D$ and $g \circ f$ is *homotopic* to $\operatorname{id}_C$.

Finally, a chain complex $C$ is said to be contractible if it is homotopy equivalent to the zero complex. If you unpack the definition, it means that there exists linear maps $h : C_n \to C_{n+1}$ such that for all $x \in C$,
$$x = dh(x) + h(dx).$$

Note that this is *not* equivalent to having vanishing homology (a condition called acyclicity). For example, the following chain complex is acyclic but not contractible:
$$\dots \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2 \cdot} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0.$$
Indeed if it were contractible, then the exact sequence would split, which isn't the case.

Comment: Typo : $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ instead of $\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z$ right ?

Comment: @Pece Yes, thanks.